# Mock a method with 4 params (including object array)

Tags: java, junit, mockito

I'm trying to mock a method with the following signature using Mockito:

```
getMessage(String arg0, Object[] arg1, String arg2, Locale arg3)
```

I've tried using many combinations of matchers including:

```
Mockito.when(messageSource.getMessage(any(),
                                      any(),
                                      any(), 
                                      any()
                                      )
            ).thenReturn(testString);
```

However, all yield the following error:

```
org.mockito.exceptions.misusing.InvalidUseOfMatchersException: 
Invalid use of argument matchers!
3 matchers expected, 4 recorded:
This exception may occur if matchers are combined with raw values:
    //incorrect:
someMethod(anyObject(), "raw String");
When using matchers, all arguments have to be provided by matchers.
For example:
//correct:
someMethod(anyObject(), eq("String by matcher"));

For more info see javadoc for Matchers class.
```

How can I mock such a method?

Comment: Post a complete example reproducing the problem (class being mocked + test).

Comment: In particular if there is any use of matchers _above_ this line, please add them in; also, please check that the `MessageSource` class and methods you're mocking are non-`final`; I have a hunch that Mockito thinks you're mocking a different method than you are trying to mock, due to `final`.

Comment: Yes, you're right. It happens to be that `Locale` is a `final` class. That's why the exception.

Comment: No, that's not the reason of the exception. String is a final class too. You're not mocking Locale in the code you posted.

Answer (score 0):

```
Mockito.when(messageSource.getMessage(any(),
            any(Object[].class),
            any(),
            any()
            )
    ).thenReturn(testString);
```

should do the trick